# Auto-indent with spaces, but insert TAB when I press the TAB key

Tags: indentation, tab-characters

I like to indent my shell scripts with two spaces instead of a TAB. So, I set `setlocal shiftwidth=2` in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/sh.vim`. It works, but I noticed that when the indentation level gets greater than 8 spaces, Vim replaces them with a tab. So, I also added "setlocal expandtab" in this file.

Unfortunately, this replaces *all* tabs by 8 spaces, even the ones inserted when I press the TAB key.

I'm looking for suitable settings to *always* have indentation (automatic or manual) composed of spaces only, but still insert a real tab when I press the TAB key.

On other Q&A, I found functions to toggle between spaces and tabs, but I'm looking for a solution which doesn't involve any kind of toggling.

Likewise, sticking with `shiftwidth` only and use `:retab` from time to time after momentarily enabling `expandtab` would not be a suitable solution (let alone the fact that since tabs and spaces are indistinguishable on screen, I wouldn't know when a file needs to be "retabbed").

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can always type a literal tab using `<c-v><tab>`.  Thus, you can `set expandtab` to always keep indent spaces, and use

```
inoremap <tab> <c-v><tab>
```

to always insert a tab character when pressing the tab key.  You should not use `:retab` at all in this case, since it will convert your tabs into spaces.

Comment: This works like a charm ! I used `inoremap <buffer> <tab> <c-v><tab>` to make it local to the buffer, since it will be used in an "after" file for Vim's default sh filetype plugin.

Also, a bit of explanation for people (like me) not familiar with Vim's map commands: noremap stands for **no**n **re**cursive **map**, and not **no** **remap**, as one would intuitively think. The starting **i** makes it active only in Insert mode.

Comment: This is a Vimscript line which can easily be written in Lua like this: `vim.api.nvim_set_keymap('i', '<tab>', '<c-v><tab>', { noremap = true })`. Thanks to [this Reddit comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/neovim/comments/xilic1/comment/ip3saw1/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web3x&utm_name=web3xcss&utm_term=1&utm_content=share_button).