# Make Vim _really_ work with both spaces and tabs

Tags: vimrc, indentation

Here is what I use for indentation:

```
set autoindent
set breakindent
set expandtab
set smarttab
set shiftround
set shiftwidth=2 softtabstop=-1  " or maybe shiftwidth=2 softtabstop=8

" https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/15557
inoremap <tab> <c-v><tab>
```

When I press >>, this indents my code 2 spaces; and when I press Tab,
this inserts the tab character. Fine, isn't it?

However, there is a problem.

```
t------> // 1 tab

s....... // 7 spaces
```

Enter the Insert mode, put the cursor after the trailing tab or the trailing spaces, and press the Backspace key.

```
Here is how I would like it to work:

t // tab has been removed

s...... // 5 spaces

And here is how it actually works:

t..... // 5 spaces

s..... // 5 spaces
```

Of course, I can replace `set shiftwidth=2 softtabstop=-1` with
`shiftwidth=2 softtabstop=8`, but there will be another problem:

```
Instead of

t

s...... // 5 spaces

It will be

t

s
```

**So my question:**

How can I set up Vim so that...

- When I press >>, it will indent code with 2 spaces
- When I press Tab in Insert mode, it will insert the tab character
- When I press Backspace and there are spaces before it, Backspace should remove 2 spaces per keypress
- When I press Backspace and there are tabs before it, Backspace should remove 1 tab per keypress

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you described in your question, and [as Matt confirmed in his answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/38110/343), you cannot do this using only Vim's options.

We are, therefore, going to have to set up a mapping. There are several ways you could go about this, but here's how I'd do it:

```
set shiftwidth=2 softtabstop=0 noexpandtab
inoremap <expr> <BS> col('.') > 2 &&
  \ col('.') % 2 == 1 &&
  \ getline('.')[col('.') - 3:col('.') - 2] == '  '
  \ ? '<BS><BS>' : '<BS>'
```

This sets up an expression mapping so when you press <kbd>Backspace</kbd> it checks the text behind the cursor and backspaces *twice* if two spaces should be deleted.

N.B. You don't mention this in your requirements, but I made it only delete two spaces if the cursor is already at a multiple of 2. Because you have `'shiftround'` set, this is how <kbd>></kbd><kbd>></kbd> and <kbd><</kbd><kbd><</kbd> will work for you, so I thought you'd want <kbd>Backspace</kbd> to work in the same way. If you don't like this, you can delete the entire line `\ col('.') % 2 == 1 &&`.

Comment: Rich, thanks a lot for this mapping, but it seems there is an error. For example, if `x` is indented by 4 spaces, the Backspace moves it from the 5th column to 4th and then to the 2nd (whereas it is expected that it will move `x` from the 5th column to the 3rd and then to the 1st).

Comment: @johnc.j. Whoops! Sorry. Thanks for letting me know. The current version should now work correctly.

Answer (score 4):

> 1. When I press >>, it will indent code with 2 spaces

```
setlocal shiftwidth=2
```

> 2. When I press Tab in Insert mode, it will insert the tab character

```
setlocal noexpandtab
```

> 3. When I press Backspace and there are spaces before it, Backspace should remove 2 spaces per keypress

```
setlocal softtabstop=2
```

> 4. When I press Backspace and there are tabs before it, Backspace should remove 1 tab per keypress

```
setlocal softtabstop=0
```

Obviously, 3 and 4 are incompatible with each other. You may also try `setlocal shiftwidth=2 softtabstop=0 smarttab`. Then at start of line backspace counts as "2 spaces" while in the middle as "1 space or tab".